# How to serialize data of model User since another model Userfull

Tags: python, json, django, django-models, django-serializer

I'm using a model for save some data of my user different to model User of contrib.auth.user and now I need get a json using django.core.serializers with some data of those models.

The model 'Usuario' save data as name and phone and role (The role is a integer that segment the users)

```
class User_info(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)

    name=models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    phone=models.IntegerField(default=0, null=False)
    role=models.ForeignKey(type_role, default=3)

class type_role(models.Model):
    type=models.IntegerField()
```

For get a QuerySet and serlize my data I'm using that view

```
def list_clients(request):
    clients = User_info.objects.filter(role_id=3)
    data=serializers.serialize('json',clientes)

    return HttpResponse(data, content_type="application/json")
```

But I'm getting a JSON as the next

```
[{
  "model": "user_info.user_info", 
  "pk": 1, 
  "fields": {
      "username": 1, 
      "name": "George",
      "phone": 5244356, 
      "role": 3
    }
}]
```

And I really need the user__username not the user__id

I know that can get this using .values(), but ValuesQuerySet aren't supported for serlizer and I get a error: 'dict' object has no attribute '_meta'

If anyone can help me I would be very thankful.

Comment: [Did you read the docs?](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/serialization/#natural-keys)

Comment: If you're doing complex serialization, you should really look at django-rest-framework.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, Yes, I want learn Django-Rest-Framework, but for now I have that resolve this problem using only Django

Comment: if you want to use serializers then it would be a less than 10 lines code solution

Answer (score 0):

change Model `User` in django.contrib.auth.models(line 369 in django 1.11.2) by add method `natural_key` or extend a new one(this would be better,don't forget to set `AUTH_USER_MODEL = "user.User"` in settings.py’ if you extent a new user model).

```
class User(AbstractUser):

    class Meta(AbstractUser.Meta):
        swappable = 'AUTH_USER_MODEL'

    def natural_key(self):
        return self.username
```

view.py

```
 clients = News.objects.filter(id=11)
 data = serializers.serialize('json', clients, use_natural_foreign_keys=True)
```

your will get:

```
[{"model": "news.news", "pk": 11, "fields": {"publisher": "schoolms", "view_times": 0, "is_top": false, "status": 0, "publish_time": "2017-06-23T15:37:00", "create_time": "2017-06-23T15:37:53.186", "update_time": "2017-06-23T15:37:53.186"}}]
```

publisher is something your want,[doc is here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/serialization/#natural-keys).

Comment: for the answer but it does not seem very good to extend user model just for a dead simple thing.

Comment: that makes sense,but i think add is better than change.

Comment: Why are you replacing the user model? And no, this isn't easier with DRF and you inherit "their way or the high way" unneeded complexity. If your end goal is what DRF provides, then go for it. Just using bits is going to become a nightmare.

Comment: I had already read that in the documentation but it seemed to me that modifying django's own elements was not convenient, I'm using heroku to deploy and any django 1.11 installed will be different than this could run this, so choose to look at QuerySet.

Comment: I don't know queryset can achieve this,this will be fine if your can achieve this by queryset.

Answer (score 0):

The serializer is built to create fixtures: it creates a model representation that can be imported into the database.
If you need a different representation, don't use the serializer. Simply create a dict representation of your model and feed it to json.dumps() or directly to JSONResponse if you're doing this in a view.

But in this case, we can use the serializer. Here's the full monty with some style fixes:

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings


class Role(models.Model):
    role_type = models.IntegerField()  # type is a built-in keyword


class UserInfoManager(models.Manager):
    def get_by_natural_key(self, username):
        return self.get(user__username=username)


class UserInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    phone = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=False)
    role = models.ForeignKey(Role, default=3)

    def natural_key(self):
        # Always return an iterable
        return [self.user.username]
```

views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.core import serializers
from .models import UserInfo


def list_clients(request):
    clients = UserInfo.objects.filter(role_id=3)
    data = serializers.serialize('json', clients, use_natural_foreign_keys=True)
    return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
```

And here's the alternative approach, where you have a whole lot more freedom:

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings


class Role(models.Model):
    role_type = models.IntegerField()  # type is a built-in keyword


class UserInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    phone = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=False)
    role = models.ForeignKey(Role, default=3)

    def model_to_dict(self):
        model_string = '.'.join([self._meta.app_label,
                                self._meta.model_name.lower()])
        field_data = dict(
            user=self.user.username, name=self.name, phone=self.phone,
            role=self.role.id, i_can_put_anything_i_want_here=True
        )
        return {
            'model': model_string,
            'pk': self.pk,
            'fields': field_data,
        }
```

views.py:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from .models import UserInfo


def list_clients(request):
    clients = UserInfo.objects.filter(role_id=3)
    results = [m.model_to_dict() for m in clients]
    data = {
        'results': {
            'count': clients.count(),
            'data': results
        }
    }
    return JsonResponse(data)
```